# Обособляется ли «в той или иной мере»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, грамматика

Контекст: «...Я тоже(,) в той или иной мере(,) учёный».

Comment: Нужен более полный контекст, так  как обособление во много зависит от структуры самого предложения, а также от сопутствующего текста. Должна быть понятной высказанная  мысль. Оборот может быть попутным замечанием (тогда он обособляется) или входить в основное сообщение.

Answer (score 2):

Не обособляется. Процитирую справочник O. A. Остроумовой, О. Д. Фрамполь:

**В ТОЙ ИЛИ ИНОЙ СТЕПЕНИ [МЕРЕ]**, наречное выражение.
Невводное, употребляется в функции обстоятельства меры и степени, не обособляется: *Он это помнил, и он знал, что все дети **в той или иной степени** проходят эту стадию космической грусти* (Ф. Искандер); *И все они были **в той или иной степени** биты и потасканы жизнью и в конце концов смирились в своих домах-пристанях или коммунальных квартирках* (Ф. Искандер); *Он написал целый цикл великолепных стихотворений, посвященных
своей последней жене, где **в той или иной мере** не слишком навязчиво, но определенно указывалось на ее глухоту* (Ф. Искандер).

Для подобных выражений правила обычно позволяют авторскую пунктуацию при желании особо выделить интонационные паузы, но злоупотреблять этим не стоит.
В Нац. корпусе статистика примерно такая: в 95% случаев обособления нет; 2% — обособление в текстах митрополитов, протоиереев, протопресвитеров и т. п. (но у них могут быть свои традиции); 2% — обособление на форумах, в старинных текстах и в не особо солидных изданиях; 1% — обособление в нормальных текстах.

Comment: @Римма Спасибо! Что ж это я так?

Comment: Пожалуйста. Да, я тоже удивилась, поэтому быстренько все исправила.

Answer (score 1):

Сравним два похожих предложения с разной пунктуацией.

*(1) Я тоже  **в той или иной мере учёный**, так как в этой области науки уже не первый год.*

(2) *В этой области науки я работаю уже давно, у меня много статей в серьезных научных изданиях.  **Я тоже, в той или иной мере, учёный.***

**ПОЯСНЕНИЕ**

1. Как известно, вводные слова относятся **к определенной тематике** и при этом очень часто имеют **парные варианты** в виде необособленных наречных выражений. Их различение делается **по семантике  и структуре** конкретного предложения.
2. Сочетание   «в той или иной мере» можно отнести к тематике **вводных слов**, но решение  все равно надо принимать для конкретного случая.
3. **Розенталь**  о тематике вводных слов:  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122   Пункт 1 (7)

(7) вводные слова (сочетания), **указывающие оценку меры** того, о чем говорится (самое большее, самое меньшее, по крайней мере, без преувеличений и др.): Разговаривал со мной, по крайней мере, как командующий армией (Сим.); Я, без всяких преувеличений, глядел на вас как на существо высшее (Т.);

4. Из материалов на форуме

http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/2390747-v-toj-ili-inoj-stepeni-vydeljaetsja-zapjatymi-ili-net.html
Пример с обособлением: Все мы в глубине души дети, **в той или иной степени.**  Авторское решение, дополнительное замечание.

[https://orfogrammka.ru/пунктуация/](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/)
запятые_при_вводных_словах_с_распространением/

Вводные слова и сочетания слов:  и) выражают ограничение или уточнение высказывания: без преувеличения, **в той или иной степени**, по крайней мере, по меньшей мере .

5. В Нацкорпусе оборот чаще всего **оборот** **не обособляется**, в этих случаях он **естественно встраивается** в предложение: Совокупность перечисленных свойств **в той или иной мере** присуща любой сложной системе. [И. М. Гуревич., 2003.11.24]
   Тем не менее обороты с обособлением **тоже встречаются**:

Все это оборудование, **в той или иной мере,** могут использовать в личных целях. [Форум: Реставрация книг. Переплетное дело (2007)]

Распределение общего объема денежных доходов по субъектам РФ не является аналогом распределения СВРП, и причины этой деформации нуждаются в специальном исследовании, поскольку именно они могут определять **(в той или иной мере)** нарастающее расслоение населения страны по уровню среднедушевых денежных доходов. «Вопросы статистики», 2004.05.27

Все что я пишу, **в той или иной мере, явно или тайно,** связано с масонскими идеями, как я их понимаю. [Георгий Орлов. Галерея масонских портретов «Лебедь», 2003.08.11]

Comment: *Sharon* (без обид!), Вы всегда говорите, что нужно быть очень внимательным и разборчивым при цитировании. Стараюсь. Именно поэтому обращаю Ваше внимание на то, что два предложения процитированы неверно. Правильно: [Георгий Орлов. Галерея масонских портретов // Интернет-альманах «Лебедь», 2003.08.11]. Запятая перед "в той или иной мере" закрывает придаточное, а вот перед самим придаточным (после "всё") она почему-то отсутствует. Я бы не стала приводить в качестве примера это пунктуационно неправильное предложение. Да и авторство предложения о распределении СВРП обкорнано.

Comment: Римма, я сокращаю длинные цитаты, чтобы не занимать много места, могу и ошибиться – внимательность, увы, не мое достоинство, так что простите, если что не так :). Но только не упрекайте  в намеренном искажении источника, это не мой стиль. Да и что эти примеры вообще доказывают в данном случае?  Обычно этот оборот не обособляется, потому что не требуется его смысловое выделение. Но есть случаи, когда эта информация дается в качестве попутного или особо выделенного замечания, вот тогда мы его обособляем. Причем это видно по структуре предложения.

Comment: У нас нет закрепленного списка вводных слов. Но даже назвав сочетание вводным или невводным, мы ничего не решаем. Обстоятельственный оборот не нуждается в обязательном значении вводности, чтобы быть обособленным – вот главная мысль. Количество примеров здесь ничего не значит. Вы можете взять ЛЮБОЕ предложение, изменить позицию оборота, и тогда потребуется его обособление. И это самое общее свойство всех обособленных конструкций. Если мне потребуется обособление, то я просто изменю структуру предложения.